# How to reload the fragment with new dimensions when the screen orientation changes

Tags: android

I have a fragment, in which a **TextView** takes it's width from folders:

`values` and `values-port`.

and these values change when there is an orientation change, but the fragment's UI doesn't have any effect.

In fact it actually picks values from `values-port` and:

**if the device is in landscape mode: onConfigurationChanged() with new orientation as landscape is called.**

**if the device is in portrait mode: onConfigurationChanged() is not called.**

and when ever I change the orientation, then `onConfigurationChanged()` is definitely called.

So,

Why does it always starts with portrait mode?

What to do to have the effect of dimensions change of the UI elements.

I tried something like this in the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    getView().requestLayout();
}
```

But doesn't work.

My **TextView** is always with the width from `values-port` folder.

**EDIT : might seem redundant, but this is the code:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".FeedActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
}
```

I know I could have removed `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` from the manifest instead of `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);` in the Activity, but want to know the behavior with this code.

Comment: display your code and your manifest ..

Comment: Why does it always starts with portrait mode?
 - you can remove this code to set the orientation to automatic
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: @waelhe Yeah it might, but the major problem is, the UI doesn't take any effect when orientation is changed. Like lets say it starts with proper dimensions after removing `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`, but how to change the width of the TextView with the new dimensions after orientation change

Comment: try creating different layouts for orientations e.g. put your landscape layout to folder layout-land and portrait layout to folder layout-port

Comment: How do you load your `Fragment`?

Comment: @curtisLoew it is in the Activity's xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FeedActivity` has a fixed orientation, specified in your manifest by the attribute `android:screenOrientation`. Therefore it will do nothing when you rotate your device. Even if it would, you’re overriding the `android:configChanges`. Here’s what [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) say:

> Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its `onConfigurationChanged()` method is called.

Your manifest tells the system that `FeedActivity` will handle orientation, screenSize and keyboard configuration changes itself. Alas, you don’t really do that.

Since you say you’re loading your `Fragment` in `XML`, I’ll assume it looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:layout_width="@dimen/frag_width"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:tag="your_tag_here"
              class="path.to.your.Fragment"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

To get the behaviour you’re expecting, you should update the manifest with

```
<activity
    android:name=".FeedActivity"
    android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```

*UPDATE*

If you insist on changing your `Fragment` width with `onConfigurationChanged` method, this could work:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    final View view = getView();
    if (null != view) {
        view.getLayoutParams().width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.width);
    }
}
```

I would advise against this approach though.

Comment: `Alas, you don’t really do that`. Okay I want to do that, I can see the dimensions change in `onConfigurationChanged` of the fragment, but how to tell the View to use those updated dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just put the fragments with different code for landscape in 'layout-land' folder.
When the screen orientation changes to landscape all the layout and fragments will be called from this folder.
So you can copy your fragment, do necessary changes for landscape mode and put it in 'layout-land' folder.
This should do the trick.